# Full width overlapping triangles

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I currently need to make something with CSS that would look like this:

[image: Full width overlapping triangles]

I managed to do it with this:

```css
.top {
  position: relative;
}
.top .gray-bar {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #cdcbcc;
  -ms-transform: rotate(1.2deg);
  transform: rotate(1.2deg);
  margin-top: -25px;
  z-index: 2;
}
.top .cyan-bar {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 90px;
  background-color: #2ca1ab;
  -ms-transform: rotate(-3deg);
  transform: rotate(-3deg);
  z-index: 1;
  margin-top: -30px;
  margin-left: -400px;
}
.top .purple-bar {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #b71e4c;
  -ms-transform: rotate(0.7deg);
  transform: rotate(0.7deg);
  margin-top: -5px;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="top">
  <div class="gray-bar"></div>
  <div class="cyan-bar"></div>
  <div class="purple-bar"></div>
</div>
```

However, when I resize my window, at some point of time, the "cyan" triangle is causing issue because of the margins and the rotation. Therefore, I added some media queries to modify the rotation angle depending on the width of the screen but I feel that it's a bit "playing around" and that there is a better solution to achieve this.

I tried using borders to make the overlapping triangles but as it cannot be expressed as percentage, I'm a bit stuck. Indeed, the goal is that the result looks about the same whatever the user's screen resolution.

Is there a better solution than mine ?

Comment: I though about it and I wanted to avoid it in order to do everything in CSS but maybe it is a better solution. I was just wondering if there was an easy way to do it just with CSS. And if I do that, it means that the image has to be very wide I guess ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Considering that the `.top` element uses the full viewport width, you can use [viewport percentage units](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#Viewport-percentage_lengths) for the borders. This will make the triangles relative to the viewport width.
See this example with one div :

```css
body,html{margin:0;padding:0;}

.topBar{
  position:relative;
  height:35px;
  border-bottom:30px solid transparent;
  border-right:100vw solid #B71E4C;   
}
.topBar:before, .topBar:after{
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  top:0; left:0;
  height:15px;
}
.topBar:before{
  border-bottom:50px solid transparent;
  border-left:100vw solid #2CA1AB;
}
.topBar:after{
  border-bottom:40px solid transparent;
  border-right:100vw solid #CDCBCC;   
}
```

```html
<div class="topBar"></div>
```

Comment: Wow, awesome, didn't know about that "vw" unit. I'll read about it right away, thanks a lot ;-)

Comment: Would you have any idea why there is an horizontal scrollbar with IE ?

Comment: @ssougnez make sure all parents (up to the `<html>` tag) have no margin, border or padding. I can't test on IE but it's the only obvious reason I can think of.

Comment: I added "html, body { margin:0; padding:0; }", however, I still have the scrollbar. Same bahaviour in the latest version of Firefox. The div is a direct child of the body element.

Comment: @ssougnez when I test my snippet in latest FF (44.0.2), there is no horizontal scrollbar.

Comment: Ok, sorry. I just removed the rest of my HTML code and the scrollbar disappear. It must be coming from something else in my page. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this help you, but, @web-tiki its the best solution, using pseudo-selectors: `:before` & `:after`

```css
.top {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 90px;
}
.top .gray-bar {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color:#cdcbcc;
    -ms-transform: rotate(1.3deg);
    transform: rotate(1.3deg);
    margin-top:-35px;
    z-index: 2;
}

.top .cyan-bar {
    position: relative;
    width: 150%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color:#2ca1ab;  
    -ms-transform: rotate(-2deg);
    transform: rotate(-2deg);
    z-index:1;
    top: -5px;
    margin-top:-30px;
    margin-left:-100px;
}

.top .purple-bar {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
    background-color:#b71e4c;   
    -ms-transform: rotate(0.7deg);
    transform: rotate(0.7deg);
    margin-top: -20px;
    z-index:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="top">
    <div class="gray-bar"></div>
    <div class="cyan-bar"></div>
    <div class="purple-bar"></div>
</div>
```